# Dúvidas com PHP

Tags: php, css, html5, pear

Estou fazendo um código e está dando esse erro:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function send() on a non-object in /home/.../public_html/.../scripts/enviar-email.php on line 63`

Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar.
Esse é o arquivo indicado no erro:

```
if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == "post"){
    include ("Mail.php");
    include ("Mail/mime.php");

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $recipients = '';

    $headers = array
    (
      'From'    => "",
      'Reply-To' => $_POST['email'], 
      'To'      => $recipients,
      'Subject' => $_POST['assunto'],
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    );


    $html = "<HTML><BODY><font color=red>";

    foreach($_POST as $campo => $valor)
    {   
        if (stristr($valor,"Content-Type")) {
        header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
        exit;
        }

        if($campo != 'redirect')
        {
        $html .= "<br>---------------------------<br>";
        $html .= ucfirst($campo) . " = $valor";
        }

    }

    $html .= "<br>---------------------------";
    $html .= "</font></BODY></HTML>";

    $mime_params = array(
      'text_encoding' => '7bit',
      'text_charset'  => 'UTF-8',
      'html_charset'  => 'UTF-8',
      'head_charset'  => 'UTF-8'
    );

    $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);

    $mime->setHTMLBody($html);

    $body = $mime->get($mime_params);
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

    $params = array
    (
      'auth' => true,
      'host' => 'sensored',
      'username' => 'sensored',
      'password' => 'sensored'
    );

    $mail_object =& Mail::factory('smtp', $params);

    $result = $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
    if (PEAR::IsError($result)) {
        echo "Erro ao enviar mensagem. (" . $result->getMessage(). ")";
        echo "<script>window.history.back();</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso');</script>";
        echo "<script>window.history.back();</script>";
    exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Essa linha ```$mail_object =& Mail::factory('smtp', $params);``` está com o sinal de "&" na instanciação do Objeto. Isso está correto?

Comment: dê um `var_dump` em seu `$mail_object` e olhe qual o conteúdo dele

Comment: ele da null....

Comment: Antes de tu chamar a função `send` tu tem que ter certeza que o `Mail::factory(..)` retornou com sucesso uma instance do objeto, se não vai dar erro mesmo, tu pode 1. verificar por que não ta retornando o objeto ou 2. adiciona uma validação e jogar um erro se $mail_object tiver null. Bota o código do `Mail.php`, o erro deve ser lá.